# Setting static IP on Ubuntu Server 12.04 makes loss of external connection

Tags: ubuntu, static, ip

I have a problem with static IP under Ubuntu 12.04.

With DHCP I have no problem, but when I set (under `/etc/network/interfaces`) the static address, the gateway, the subnetmask and the dns-nameservers, I have that the Server cannot connect to external world.

It is able only to connect to local IP hosts.

I have tried to insert the nameservers in the `/etc/resolv.conf` but every time I restart the machine, the changes are canceled.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 19):

Ubuntu 12.04 use resolvconf (a set of scripts and hooks) instead of resolv.conf to manage DNS server. The most notable difference for the user is that any change manually done to /etc/resolv.conf will be lost as it gets overwritten next time something triggers resolvconf.

To add the static dns entries in resolv.conf file,edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`:

Add these lines (the example below is OpenDNS’s public name servers):

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Run this command to refresh the resolvconf setting:

```
sudo service resolvconf restart
```

To view your DNS Servers addresses, use this command:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Perfect answer, every step worked exactly as described for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

First of all: check if you have proper configuration:
- try to ping your gateway, is it work? If no check your gateway IP.
- try to ping 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS) - is it work? If no, check you routing using one of:

```
mtr 8.8.8.8
```

or

```
tracepath -n 8.8.8.8
```

and check at which hop the routing stops.

Regarding DNS namees: please add to the /etc/network/interfaces lines:

```
dns-nameservers Your_DNS_IP_address
```

Answer (score 0):

We have had the same problem with an old HP Terminal and Ubuntu 12.04 to use a static IP we had to use the "manual" flag in /etc/network/interfaces.and simulate an ifconfig-input.

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
 up ifconfig eth1 <IP> netmask <IP> broadcast <IP> up
 up route add default gw <IP>
```

A strange solution but the minimal amount of voodoo, to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Various processes overwrite /etc/resolv.conf (dhcpd, networkmanager, etc.).  I suspect that's the issue you are seeing.  I would suggest a few options:

1. Instead of adding the nameservers to "/etc/resolv.conf", instead add them to "/etc/resolv.conf.head".  The contents of "/etc/resolv.conf.head" will get automatically prepended to the stuff that gets automatically generated.  Depending on your options you may want to use "/etc/resolv.conf.tail" to tack on your settings at the end of the file.  Either way, this should override any of those automatically generated settings with your fixed ones.
2. Write-protect /etc/resolv.conf to prevent your changes from being overwritten by another daemon (after you make your changes):

   `$ sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`
3. Most likely it is dhcpd that is modifying /etc/resolv.conf, and you forgot to disable it.  Remove (or disable) dhcpd so it won't modify /etc/resolv.conf.  To remove:

   `$ sudo apt-get remove isc-dhcp-client`
4. Use auditd to determine which daemon is modifying /etc/resolv.conf:

   `$ sudo auditctl -w /etc/resolv.conf -p w`

The logs are in /var/log/audit/audit.log.  You can see the date/time the file was modified and what program modified it (to take corrective steps).

Comment: Oops, I got the path wrong for tail/head.  It's "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head" or "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail". In most cases, you'll create a "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail" file and add your "nameserver" settings there.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno about you, but I don't like using the `resolv.conf` file.  I prefer to set the nameserver to read my routers and typically I'll use Google's 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 name servers.

Here's a small guide I found if anyone is interested.

http://ubuntuserverhelp.com/setting-up-a-static-ip/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and comment the `dns=dnsmasq` line, then do:

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

There's a thread of this issue here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/989900